# Godaddy Changing Max Execution, max_fileuploads, memory_limit

Tags: hosting

In godaddy how to add these values

Here are required values:

```
max_execution_time 600
max_file_uploads 100
memory_limit 128M
upload_max_filesize 64M
post_max_size 64M
max_input_time 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solutions

I have updated .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```